# How to calculate frequency percentages for a table using SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, frequency

Let's say I have some data as follows:

```
 ID   data  fingers  rating
001  hello        y       0
002  hello        n       0
003    bye        n       0
004  hello        y       1
005    bye        n       0
```

All I want is a table that shows the freqency of each value in `data`

Resulting as follows:

```
 data  count  pct
hello      3   .6
  bye      2   .4
```

Feels simple but I'm struggling to make this work in Snowflake, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how you can do it:

```
select data , count(*) count, count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () pct
from table
group by data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select data, count(*),
       avg(case when fingers = 'y' then 1.0 else 0 end)
from t
group by data;
```